# Retain the value of while() generated list of checkbox fields. Value="checked" (but value has data already?)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, input, checkbox

I'm in a bit of an odd spot here. I am modifying a script, and my validation is all working fine with the exception of my checkbox input selections which are generated from an array with a `while` loop..

What I need to be able to do is retain the `value="checked"` if the box has been selected, but the value field currently stores the id value to be passed to a table, and I the value option is how the "checked" is called... So

```
...PHP_SELF...

while(...)
{
    <input name="seminar[]" type="checkbox" id="seminar[]" value="<?= $data[id] ?>">
}

...SUBMIT...
```

I am thinking I might need to store the submitted values in an array, then replace the `value="<?= $data[id] ?>"` with `value="checked"` but seems kinda wonky to me..

Anyone run into this before have an suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm. My code is not showing up again although I inserted it within the code tags.. Maybe its being moderated?

Comment: Thanks, Evan. I solved the issue already. It's about the time I lost all my hair, I post up a question and then I find the answer right afterwards! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I did not realize this, but there is an input value titled: checked which works like: checked="checked" .. Geeze this put me in my place : )